How to bug-proof sliding screen door
I have a screened sliding door on a track. The gap between the door frames of the screened door and the glass door is wide enough to let in all sorts of bugs.  What solutions are available?

Pictures of the gaps will help, but most hardware stores have a wide selection of weather stripping for most door gaps.

Depending on the design of your Patio Door, you can use one of these Patio Door Bug Strip
